# Why is $\mathcal{P}$ = SET($\mathcal{Z}$)?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, permutation-cycles, analytic-combinatorics

in the book Analytic Combinatorics, where the symbolic method is described, they say that $\mathcal{P}$ = $SET(\mathcal{Z})$ and therefore $\hat{P}(z) = exp(\hat{Z}(z))$. 
$\mathcal{P}$ denotes the family of permutations of finite sets [n] and $\mathcal{Z}$ the cyclic permutations of [n]. 
So my question is, why this is the case? How can you think about it in order to come to that conclusion?

Comment: Every permutation can be decomposed in disjoint cycles. The order of the cycles is not important.

Comment: @Phicar Thanks for commenting, but I know that and stil don't understand it, though.

Comment: It is a little unclear which part you do not understand. Do you have problem with the fact that you are dealing with labelled structures, with the set construction? Notice that in unlabelled enviroment, Set is like MSet or PSet. So like you can consider the problem in unlabelled enviroment and then do the equivalence relation.